# Scala match statement error

Tags: scala, match

I have written following simple function to demonstrate match with if condition.
It works fine for positive numbers, e.g. evenOdd(5), evenOdd(6) works just fine. But if I call evenOdd(-5), I am getting MatchError
It goes away after I add variable pattern case _

Why is this happening?

```
def evenOdd(num: Int):Unit = {
    num match {
        case n if (n % 2 == 0) => println("even")
        case n if (n % 2 == 1) => println("odd")
    }
}
```

```
scala.MatchError: -5 (of class java.lang.Integer)
at Main$$anon$1.evenOdd(Recursion.scala:17)
at Main$$anon$1.<init>(Recursion.scala:24)
at Main$.main(Recursion.scala:1)
at Main.main(Recursion.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Replace `num` with `Math.abs(num)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because -5 % 2 = -1

So there is a match error because this case is not treated.

You must add either (as you said)

```
case _ => println("not treated")
```

or `case -1 => println("odd")`